# What is the Shovel Knight shaped hole in King Knight's stage for?

Tags: shovel-knight

In King Knight's stage, there is a room with a lava bucket that tries to prevent you from crossing a gap with moving platforms spanning the aforementioned pit.  On the other side of this obstacle is, what appears to be, a Shovel Knight shaped hole and I don't know what to do with it.

I tried pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Space</kbd> and every other key I could that that might interact with it but to no avail.  Is it merely decorative?  I mean the obstacle preventing you from getting to this hole isn't impossible, but it **is** a little unrewarding if this thing doesn't serve a purpose.

[image: Shovel Knight shaped hole]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hole is a secret passage.  You don't press any keys to make it work, you just need to line yourself up with it fairly well and then wait a few seconds.  Then you will be sent through the secret passage.  I was too impatient to get it to work because I kept mashing keys and trying to re-align myself with it to let it actually trigger.